# Implement autoComplete on a jCombobox

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jcombobox, listcellrenderer

I have a jCombobox that has the list of countries. It is populated by a database and contains countryID and countryName, So only the country name is shown in the combo box but when clicked on a value it will return the selected  country's id. I have managed to achieve this using custom ListCellRenderer.

```
public class UGIS_ComboboxRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {

@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    Object[] itemData = (Object[]) value;
    setText((String) itemData[1]);
    return this;
}
}
```

A single country Object will look similar to this

```
Object[] country1 = new Country(){1, "United Kingdom"}
```

I have an ArrayList of Objects like above and add them to the combobox like this

```
for (Object[] temp : countrylist) {
        jComboBox1.addItem(temp); 
                }
```

Now what I want is to have an AutoComplete feature for this combobox so that the user can type the country name and efficiently navigate to the "Area of interest" in the combo box list. Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

> Now what I want is to have an AutoComplete feature for this combobox so that the user can type the country name and efficiently navigate to the "Area of interest" in the combo box list

This is default functionality of a JComboBox. As you type characters the selection will move to items in the list that contain those characters.

> It is populated by a database and contains countryID and countryName, So only the country name is shown in the combo box but when clicked on a value it will return the selected country's id. I have managed to achieve this using custom ListCellRenderer.

A custom renderer breaks the default functionality as described above.

See [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) for a solution that also implements the KeySelectionManager so the keyboard selection functionality will still work.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this tutorial of Autocomplete](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/07/19/adding-auto-completion-to-swing-comboboxes.html).

Once you've gone over that, you can do something like...

```
this.countries = new JComboBox(new Object[] {"United States", "United Kingdom", "Canada", "Mexico"});
AutoCompleteDecorate.decorate(this.countries);
```

Comment: It didn't work. it is throwing a class cast exception since my objects are formatted like Object[]{countriID, countryName}